# Boolean expression must not be null when saving form flutter

Tags: flutter, boolean, assertion

am trying to save the formState in the elevated button below but, the validation goes through but when it starts saving I get this error : 'boolean expression must not be null', and I don't have any boolean to save.
I tried adding onSaved inside the dropDowns but still the same issue, anyone can help please?

```
class OfferPriceAndUsageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Consumer<AddOfferProvider>(
      builder: (context, provider, snapshot) {
        return Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CenteredSubtitleWidget(label: 'Prix et usage'),
              LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  final List<bool> searchType = [
                    provider.isBuy(),
                    !provider.isBuy(),
                  ];
                  return ToggleButtons(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                      width: size.width / 2.1,
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    isSelected: searchType,
                    borderColor: Colors.teal.shade700,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    children: [
                      Text("Vente"),
                      Text("Location"),
                    ],
                    onPressed: (index) {
                      switch (index) {
                        case 0:
                          provider.setBuy();
                          break;
                        case 1:
                          provider.setRent();
                          break;
                        default:
                          print('Error selecting the objectif.');
                          break;
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              verticalSpacer,
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                decoration: buildDropDownInputDecoration(hint: 'Usage'),
                hint: Text("Usage"),
                items: generateTerrainUsage(),
                value: provider.offerInformation['usage'],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  provider.setUsage(value);
                },
              ),
              verticalSpacer,
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      initialValue: '20',
                      enabled: !provider.offerInformation['hidePrice'],
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        if (provider.offerInformation['ispricePerMeter'])
                          provider.offerInformation['pricePerMeter'] = value;
                        provider.offerInformation['price'] = value;
                      },
                      validator: requiredElementValidator,
                      decoration: buildFormInputDecoration(
                        label: 'Prix (DT)',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  horizontalSpacer,
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        provider.offerInformation['surface'] = value;
                      },
                      validator: requiredElementValidator,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: buildFormInputDecoration(
                        label: 'Surface (m²)',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Checkbox(
                    value: provider.offerInformation['hidePrice'],
                    onChanged: provider.toggleHidePrice,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      return provider.toggleHidePrice(
                        !provider.offerInformation['hidePrice'],
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text("Cacher le prix"),
                  ),
                  if (!provider.offerInformation['hidePrice']) ...[
                    Checkbox(
                      value: provider.offerInformation['isPricePerMeter'],
                      onChanged: provider.togglePricePerMeter,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        return provider.togglePricePerMeter(
                          !provider.offerInformation['isPricePerMeter'],
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text("Prix par m²"),
                    ),
                  ]
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        try {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate())
                            _formKey.currentState.save();
                          // print(provider.offerInformation);
                        } catch (e) {
                          print(e);
                          print(provider.offerInformation);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text("Valider"),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the currentState getter:

> The current state is null if (1) there is no widget in the tree that matches this global key, (2) that widget is not a [StatefulWidget], or the associated [State] object is not a subtype of T.

Switch to a StatefulWidget and add a null check to currentState

`_formKey.currentState!.validate()`
`_formKey.currentState!.save()`